# Batch script interrupts after executing npm.cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, npm, command

The following batch script is given:

```
set JAVA_HOME="%cd%\tools\java\windows\jdk"
set PATH="C:\Windows\System32";"%cd%\tools\maven\bin";"%cd%\tools\nodejs"
cd apps\build\nodejs && npm install gulp
%cd%\tools\java\windows\jdk\bin\java.exe -jar tool.jar
```

Now this command
`%cd%\tools\java\windows\jdk\bin\java.exe -jar tool.jar` will be

no longer executed after this 
`cd apps\build\nodejs && npm install gulp`

is executed. Actually the command prompt just closed after execution.

What is the reason for this?

**My npm.cmd** (i can't edit this file)

```
:: Created by npm, please don't edit manually.
@ECHO OFF

SETLOCAL

SET "NODE_EXE=%~dp0\node.exe"
IF NOT EXIST "%NODE_EXE%" (
  SET "NODE_EXE=node"
)

SET "NPM_CLI_JS=%~dp0\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('CALL "%NODE_EXE%" "%NPM_CLI_JS%" prefix -g') DO (
  SET "NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS=%%F\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
)
IF EXIST "%NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS%" (
  SET "NPM_CLI_JS=%NPM_PREFIX_NPM_CLI_JS%"
)

"%NODE_EXE%" "%NPM_CLI_JS%" %*
```

Comment: I suspect this seems a `PATH` error. Have you tried `set PATH=%PATH%;"%cd%\tools\maven\bin";"%cd%\tools\nodejs"`? To get any errors, open cmd, `cd` to the folder where your batch file is, and run it by typing its name. How is your batch file named?

Comment: @double-beep, although not forbidden, I recommend not to include quotes into the `PATH` variable, because this seems to be standard in Windows. Note also that modifying `PATH` with `set` is just valid for the current `CMD` session...

Comment: @aschipfl is he going to use it in an another session?

Comment: @double-beep, don't think so, but I just wanted to point that out (particularly for the OP), as this is often the reason for troubles people are running in...

Comment: Precede `npm` by `call`; since `npm` is a batch file, you need `call` to return control to the calling script after finishing...

Comment: Sorry, I've been busy. Thanks for your help.  @aschipfl's answer worked - Call was the solution.
The script still doesn't do what I want. I can't get back to you until tomorrow, I'm in meetings all day today.

Comment: 1. Change `set VAR="Value"` to `set "VAR=Value"`, so the quotes do not become part of the value. 2. Try to use absolute paths, so `cd foo\bar` becomes `cd /D "D:\root\foo\bar"`. 3. Quote all paths, so `D:\root\foo\bar\some.exe` becomes `"D:\root\foo\bar\some.exe"`, which protects whitespaces and other special characters...